# Properly call a generic function in Haxe 3

Tags: generics, syntax, haxe

The following function does nothing useful, but illustrates the syntax I am trying to use.

```
@:generic public static function newPoint<T: Dynamic>(point: Point<T> = null): Point<T>
{
    if (point == null)
        point = new Point<T>();
    return point;
}
```

How is T determined/passed?  `var pt: Point<Int> = newPoint<Int>();` gives me an error, same with `var pt: Point<Int> = newPoint();`

So what is the correct way of calling such a generic function?  Hours of searching for an example have given me nothing - Haxe really is a black box at times.

Here is another example:

```
@:generic static private function randomElement<T>(array: Array<T>, usedIndices: Map<Int, Int> = null): T
{
  var ix: Int;

  if (usedIndices != null)
  {
    do {
      ix = Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length);
    } while (usedIndices.exists(ix) == true);

    usedIndices.set(ix, 0);
  }
  else {
    ix = Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length);
  }

  return array[ix];
}
```

Now this works flawlessly for me:

```
var elems: Array<Int> = [2, 3, 8, 7, 11, 16];
var elem: Int = randomElement(elems);
```

So it looks like the <T> is determined automatically properly, although I don't know *how* exactly.  It can make sense, but what are the *precise* rules?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is real question or just to test how generic functions work.

In your example the assumptions are a bit weird. Imaging that you use Point, which should be possible with generic classes. How would `point.x = 5` ever would work? So why do you want Point to be generic and what do you want to ?

To better understand how generic functions could work, I find the Lambda class a useful reference.
https://github.com/HaxeFoundation/haxe/blob/development/std/Lambda.hx

Comment: Hi Mark.  Perhaps the example is not clear; to be more precise, I have a set of classes, Point2i, Point2f, Point3i, Point3f, etc.  Now creating a class hierarchy is easy for the same data types (Point2i and Point3i for example which both use integer components), however I wanted to create a single class with a generic data type.  By chance I copied one of the static public methods which is where I experienced the unusual behavior and it looks a bit odd by itself.

Comment: The Lambda class is a nice example, so thanks for that.  However, what I'd really like to know about is the calling syntax.  I edited the example to make it seem more sensible.